# Creating index on sorted data

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures, nosql

I have a text file with some sorted data, splitted with newline. for example:

`...

abc123

abc124

abd123

abd124

abd125

...`

Now I want to create an index for the dataset, which should (at least) support:

1. **getStringByIndex(n)**: return nth item of the sorted list;
2. **getIndexByString(s)**: find s in all items, return its index (or -1 if not found);

I've read some indexing algorithms like hashing and B-Trees. A B-Tree with an extra field of children size should do that well. but since the dateset is sorted, I wonder if there is a more effecient solution than building a B-Tree by inserting all items into it?

Comment: Can I create a datastructure? Say a datastructure that has an Array and a hashset. Inserting into an array is easy and everytime you insert it into an array, insert that item into the hashset. When you do getStringByIndex, use the array and for getIndexByString, use the hashset?

Comment: It's more likely a "database" instead of an on-memory structure. The index should be stored on disk file.

Comment: The dataset can be as large as 100GB and cannot be loaded into memory. otherwise a simple binary search can solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data is sorted, you can locate content very quickly and efficiently by just keeping a small, sparse subset of the data in memory.  For example, let's say we decide to store every Nth element in memory.  For efficient initialization of your API, you'd want to compile this sparse list in a separate file on disk, so you don't have to stream through 100GB of data to get it.

For each of these terms, you need to save the disk offset relative to the head of the file for where the term starts.  Then, all you've got to do is load the sparse list / offset pairs into memory, and the implementations of your two requests become straightforward:

```
    getStringByIndex(n):
        Get floor(n/N)-th string/offset pair from list
        Seek offset position in index
        Read/Skip n mod N strings, then return the next one

    getIndexByString(s):
        Binary search over sparse list in memory
            Locate lower and upper bound string/offset pairs
        If a string/offset pair is in the i-th position in our sparse list,
            then the string itself is the (N x i)-th string in our index.
            We can use this information to compute the return value
        If the string we want isn't in memory:
            Seek lower-bound offset in index
            Read strings until we:
                a) Find a match
                b) Reach the high-bound offset
                c) Reach a string which is lexicographically greater than the one we are looking for
        Else
            Just return the index for the matching string in our sparse list
```

If the strings in your index are fixed-width, you can make even greater optimizations.

You will want to be careful about your choice of 'N' for this algorithm, if you implement it.  Remember, the cost of reading 10 bytes from a position on disk isn't much lower than the cost of reading 10,000 bytes from that same position:  It's the overhead of the disk seek, and getting in and out of the I/O call that hurts most.

Comment: Thanks very much for your hint. I will try a 2-level index (sparse subset of sparse subset). because for 100GB and N=4KB, I have to load 25MB index data into memory with 1-level, while 2-level only needs 6.25KB.